About V-ing as adverbials of respect
I'm currently reading 'A Comprehensive Grammar of the English Language' by Randolph Quirk et al, and there's this section that I can't make sense of. He defines an 'adverbial of respect' as


an adverbial to identify a relevant point of reference in respect of which the clause concerned derives its truth value


This type of adverbial is [in one case doubly] demonstrated in the following sentences:


So far as travelling facilities are concerned, we have obviously made a popular decision; but with respect to the date, many people
are expressing dissatisfaction.

She helped him a little with his book.

She talked learnedly about Kant.

He has always been frightened of earwigs.

They are advising me legally. [where the adverbial does not mean
'lawfully, not illegally', but 'on points of law, with respect to
law']



He goes on to make a point about how this category of adverbials is often expressed by phrases that are usually used to talk about other categories.
For example:


'He is working in a (nearby) factory'

seems concerned with where he
is working, and the adverbial expresses the locative relation: there
is a specific factory in mind. But equally, without the option of
including an indication (such as nearby) that a specific factory is in
mind, the adverbial in the following could rather serve to answer the
question 'What is he doing?' than 'Where is he working?': He is
working in a factory.  If the adverbial does indeed answer What?
rather than Where? it is being predicated of a respect relationship:
'So far as his work is concerned, it is in a factory', 'He is a
factory worker'.

The phrase in a factory answers the question 'What?', not 'Where?', which makes it an adverbial of respect, not spatial location. So far, so good as I'm perfectly able to understand this.
But then he compares these 3 sentences:


She died a peaceful death. [She died peacefully; As for her death, it was peaceful]

They split their sides laughing

He's busy writing.



This part eludes me as to how the three sentences above could be compared since there is no explanation. I fail to comprehend how writing and laughing in the last two sentences can be considered adverbials of respect.
Some other similar instances of V-ing as adverbials of respect from the book:

He stood waiting (patiently).
She sat reading (to the children).
They went hurrying (breathlessly).
She came running (in great haste).

How am I to understand all these examples as adverbials of respect realized by V-ing ? I mean, it's really difficult to paraphrase the adverbials realized by V-ing the same way we can with those by prepositional phrases:
He's afraid of earwigs. - As for what he is afraid of, it's earwigs.
She helped him a little with his book. - About what she helped him a little with, it was his book.
While it can be done with this sentence: He's busy writing - About what he's busy with, it's writing.
I can't find any sensible way to rephrase this sentence in the same vein: He stood waiting - With respect to waiting, he stood ? That makes absolutely no sense whatsoever. Same goes for 'split their sides laughing', 'sat reading, 'went hurrying', 'came running'.

You mean A Comprehensive Grammar Of The English Language by Randolph Quirk, Sidney Greenbaum, Geoffrey Leech, and Jan Svartvik (1985)? It would also help if you made it clearer what parts of your question are quotations from the book, and what are your own commentary.

Yes, that's the book. I've already edited the comment to make it right. Also, the excerpt is from section 8.6. Adverbials of respect on page 483-484 of the book.

Swan would class 'So far as travelling facilities are concerned' as a 'focusing/linking' discourse[/pragmatic] marker', here a parenthetical restricting the domain. I'd class 'She died a peaceful death' as an example of a cognate object construction, 'He stood waiting' as a phase structure (compare 'He was waiting'), and 'She came running' as postmodification by an ing-form. I'd have to regard the Quirk et al interpretation here as over-lumping and not the best.

To be fair, it is indeed stated in the book that 'a peaceful death' is a cognate object. Here I'm just confused with the semantics of the participles or how they should be interpreted. After all, in this section of the book, we are examining adverbials in terms of their semantic functions.
